# How to structure a MySQL query to join with an exclusion

Tags: mysql

> In short; we are trying to return certain results from one table based on second level criteria of another table.

I have a number of source data tables,
So:

**Table DataA:**

```
data_id | columns | stuff....
-----------------------------
   1    |  here   | etc.  
   2    |  here   | poop  
   3    |  here   | etc.
```

**Table DataB:**

```
data_id | columnz | various....
-----------------------------
   1    |  there  | you 
   2    |  there  | get  
   3    |  there  | the  
   4    |  there  | idea.
```

**Table DataC:**

```
data_id | column_s | others....
-----------------------------
   1    |  where   | you 
   2    |  where   | get  
   3    |  where   | the  
   4    |  where   | idea.
```

***Table DataD: etc. There are more and more will be added ongoing***

And a relational table of visits, where there are "visits" to some of these other data rows in these other tables above.

*Each of the above tables holds very different sets of data.*

The way this is currently structured is like this:

**Visits Table:**

```
visit_id | reference | ref_id | visit_data | columns | notes
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1    |   DataC   |   2    |  some data |  etc.   | so this is a reference 
         |           |        |            |         |   to a visit to row id
         |           |        |            |         |   2 on table DataC  
    2    |   DataC   |   3    |  some data |  etc.   |  ...  
    3    |   DataB   |   4    |  more data |  etc.   | so this is a reference 
         |           |        |            |         |   to a visit to row id
         |           |        |            |         |   4 on table DataB  
    4    |   DataA   |   1    |  more data |  etc.   | etc. etc.  
    5    |   DataA   |   2    |  more data |  etc.   | you get the idea
```

Now we currently list the visits by various user given criteria, such as visit date.
however the user can also choose which tables (ie data types) they want to view, so a user has to tick a box to show they want data from `DataA` table, and `DataC` table but not `DataB`, for example.

The SQL we currently have works like this; the column list in the `IN` conditional is dynamically generated from user choices:

```
SELECT visit_id,columns, visit_data, notes
FROM visits 
WHERE visit_date < :maxDate AND visits.reference IN ('DataA','DataC')
```

## The Issue:

Now, we need to go a step beyond this and list the visits by a sub-criteria of one of the "Data" tables,
So for example, `DataA` table has a reference to something else, so now the client wants to list all visits to numerous reference types, and **IF** the type is `DataA` then to only count the visits if the data in that table fits a value.

For example:

> List all visits to DataB and all visits to DataA where `DataA.stuff = poop`

The way we currently work this is a secondary SQL on the results of the first visit listing, exampled above. This works but is always returning the full table of `DataA` when we only want to return a subset of DataA but we can't be exclusive about it outside of `DataA`.

We can't use `LEFT JOIN` because that doesn't trim the results as needed, we can't use exclusionary joins (`RIGHT` / `INNER`) because that then removes anything from `DataC` or any other table,

We can't find a way to add queries to the `WHERE` because again, that would loose any data from any other table that is not `DataA`.

What we kind of need is a JOIN within an IF/CASE clause.

**Pseudo SQL:**

```
SELECT visit_id,columns, visit_data, notes
FROM visits 
IF(visits.reference = 'DataA')
    INNER JOIN DataA ON visits.ref_id = DataA.id AND DataA.stuff = 'poop'
ENDIF 
WHERE visit_date < 2020-12-06 AND visits.reference IN ('DataA','DataC')
```

All criteria in the `WHERE` clause are set by the user, none are static (This includes the `DataA.stuff` criteria too).

So with the above example the output would be:

> ```
> visit_id | reference | ref_id | visit_data | columns | notes
> -------------------------------------------------------------
>     1    |   DataC   |   2    |  some data |  etc.   | 
>     2    |   DataC   |   3    |  some data |  etc.   | 
>     5    |   DataA   |   1    |  more data |  etc.   |
> ```

We can't use Union because the different Data tables contain lots of different details.

## Questions:

There may be a very straightforward answer to this but I can't see it,

1. How can we approach trying to achieve this sort of partial exclusivity?
2. I suspect that our overarching architecture structure here could be improved (the system complexity has grown organically over a number of years). If so, what could be a better way of building this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What we kind of need is a JOIN within an IF/CASE clause.

Well, you should know that's not possible in SQL.

Think of this analogy to function calls in a conventional programming language. You're essentially asking for something like:

> What we need is a function call that calls a different function depending on the value you pass as a parameter.

As if you could do this:

```
call $somefunction(argument);
```

And which $somefunction you call would be determined by the function called, depending on the value of `argument`. This doesn't make any sense in any programming language.

It is similar in SQL — the tables and columns are fixed at the time the query is parsed. Rows of data are not read until the query is executed. Therefore one can't change the tables depending on the rows executed.

The simplest answer would be that you must run more than one query:

```
SELECT visit_id,columns, visit_data, notes
FROM visits 
INNER JOIN DataA ON visits.ref_id = DataA.id AND DataA.stuff = 'poop'
WHERE visit_date < 2020-12-06 AND visits.reference = 'DataA';

SELECT visit_id,columns, visit_data, notes
FROM visits 
WHERE visit_date < 2020-12-06 AND visits.reference = 'DataC';
```

Not every task must be done in one SQL query. If it's too complex or difficult to combine two tasks into one query, then leave them separate and write code in the client application to combine the results.

Comment: Thanks. This was the conclusion I was coming to but I wanted to check if there was something that I'd overlooked or missed that might have made the current shape of things work in one.

Comment: You make me think -- how about running a subquery to check the inverse value of `DataA.stuff` and then only collecting the row if the result is NULL (like `ON B.key = NULL`)? Kind of like an outer join based on a subquery result?

Comment: There is no "only join if" operation in SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong phrasing. I have updated my comment;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're describing without seeing the full example query you have in mind.. But it sounds more complex than just running two simple queries.